# Are there any Scriptures that describe Maha-Sadashiva, The 25-headed form of Shiva?

Tags: scripture, shiva, shaivism, agamas, shaiva-siddhanta

[image]

I was wondering. Is this form of Lord Shiva mentioned in any Puranas or Shaiva Agamas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

~ Caryāpāda Chapter-1
Makuta Agama, Verse 1-3.:

> कैलासवासी भगवान् महादेवो महेश्वरः । महाकैलासनिलयं महाकारुणिकोत्तमम् ।।
> पञ्चपञ्चमुखं देवं पञ्चाशद्भुजमण्डितम्।
> पञ्चब्रह्ममयं शान्तं पञ्चकृत्यपरायणम् ।।
> परं शिवं समालोक्य प्रणम्य विनयान्वितः । पप्रच्छैवं कृपाविष्टो लोकानुग्रहकाङ्क्षया ।।
>
> God Rudra, out of compassion and for the welfare of the world, approaches and most humbly bows unto **Paramasiva,** the greatest of gods, the Lord of lords, **the ruler of Mahā Kailāśa,** the supreme among all the merciful beings residing on the mount Mahā Kailasa, endowed with **twenty five faces' and fifty hands, of the nature of Pañcabrahma hymn,** immutable but ever engrossed in performing five-fold actions and enquires.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..